# Alternative for table-cell, it doesn't change with the width of the screen(wrap?)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that a `<div>` table that doesn't resize when I change the width of my screen. I know you can do this with flexbox, but I can't figure out how.

This is my current code:

CSS:

```css
.boxer-center {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
}
.boxer .box-row {
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}
.box_pricing{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="boxer-center">
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box_pricing">Hi</div>
        <div class="box_pricing">Hi</div>
        <div class="box_pricing">Hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box_pricing">asd</div>
        <div class="box_pricing">asd</div>
        <div class="box_pricing">asd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to convert it to flexbox, but it would not work for me. Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: Depending on what you're displaying, you may want to consider using an actual `<table>` element. They are intended to display tabular data. Here's an [interesting method of creating responsive tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

Comment: That really isn't an option, I want to work with DIV's, also because if I ever need this for a school thing and I use tables they won't accept it.

Comment: That's an odd requirement for a school to impose, but fair enough.

Comment: You could use a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to set table-cells to `display:block` when the screen is below a certain width, putting each cell on its own line. [See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/48f867td/5/). But I'm not sure this is what you're looking for as the readability of that layout really depends on the actual data you're trying to display. For example, if the first row consists of column headers, this may not be appropriate. Is it possible to show us an example of your actual data?

Comment: It is basically going to be something like this: http://mrgoatsy.wc.lt/index.php?p=pricing but of course with more data, but I have not figured out what to put there yet.

Comment: If the table only has two rows (headers and data), then you might be able to use CSS `:before` to generate new labels based on HTML data attributes. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/48f867td/6/) based on [this article](http://mobifreaks.com/responsive-and-seo-friendly-data-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

I had success by:

1. Setting the `display:table` element to 100% width.
2. Changing `.boxer` to `.boxer-center` as `.boxer` doesn't exist.
3. Changing `border` to `outline` so it won't affect the width of cells.

```css
.boxer-center {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;                  /* Set table to 100% width */
    /* margin:auto                  Removed this as it is not necessary */
}
.boxer-center .box-row {         /* Changed to .boxer-center, .boxer doesn't exist */
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}
.box_pricing {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: 1px dashed red;     /* Changed border to outline to preserve box model */
    min-width:100px;             /* No cell will be smaller than 100px */
}
```

[TEST IN JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/48f867td/4/)

Comment: It works, but the thing I want is that the tables go under each other when you are on a phone, this only makes it smaller.

Comment: Oh, I see. You may want to edit your question to specify *how* you want the table to change when the screen resizes. I assumed you just wanted the table to change width, but it seems that you want the cells to wrap instead.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it a little bit, not sure how to format the question any better either :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
.boxer-center {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.box-row {
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}
.box_pricing{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PeterA/z1f0L0nz/)